# spring security's searchForSingleEntryInternal method throws exception if record not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on an application that uses Spring Security's `searchForSingleEntryInternal` method. Is there a way to do the same thing without throwing an exception if a record is not found? I want to be able to create a condition that handles missing records.

### What I want to change

```
if (results.size() == 0) {
    throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, 0);
}
```

### From this method

```
/**
* Internal method extracted to avoid code duplication in AD search.
*/
public static DirContextOperations searchForSingleEntryInternal(DirContext ctx, SearchControls searchControls,
    String base, String filter, Object[] params) throws NamingException {
        final DistinguishedName ctxBaseDn = new DistinguishedName(ctx.getNameInNamespace());
        final DistinguishedName searchBaseDn = new DistinguishedName(base);
        final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> resultsEnum = ctx.search(searchBaseDn, filter, params, searchControls);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Searching for entry under DN '" + ctxBaseDn + "', base = '" + searchBaseDn + "', filter = '" + filter + "'");
        }

        Set<DirContextOperations> results = new HashSet<DirContextOperations>();
        try {
            while (resultsEnum.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult searchResult = resultsEnum.next();
                // Work out the DN of the matched entry
                DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName(new CompositeName(searchResult.getName()));

                if (base.length() > 0) {
                    dn.prepend(searchBaseDn);
                }

                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Found DN: " + dn);
                }
                results.add(new DirContextAdapter(searchResult.getAttributes(), dn, ctxBaseDn));
            }
        } catch (PartialResultException e) {
            LdapUtils.closeEnumeration(resultsEnum);
            logger.info("Ignoring PartialResultException");
        }

        if (results.size() == 0) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, 0);
        }

        if (results.size() > 1) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, results.size());
        }

        return results.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

I'm somewhat new to spring and maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy fix, just had to copy over the `searchForSingleEntryInternal` method from Spring Security and place it in my own project. From there I was able to tweak the exception handling so the application didn't come to a grinding halt if a record wasn't found.